# Variable Name Efficiency in Shader (OpenGL ES 2)

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, shader

Out of curiosity, will it be more efficient to write shader variables like this :

```
     lowp vec4 tC = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord); // texture color
```

or

```
     lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord); // texture color
```

Note that I wrote variable **tC** because it has less characters than variable **textureColor**

I understand in programming language like C/ObjC, it doesn't matter, but what about shader, since you can query the attributes / uniform names.

Comment: While at first I thought *"What a stupid question"* you indeed got some valid points. Still neither of those variables is an attribute or uniform name. And even then, you don't constantly query them each frame but usually only once. But you still have a point regarding the maintenance overhead in the driver used for attribute and uniform names, even if that will be negligable.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot, I should've shown an attribute/uniform name. But, I'm just curious, just in case we have so many attributes/uniforms per shaders, and many shaders resides in the hardware.

Comment: The hardware won't care, it doesn't know about any names. But the driver will indeed care, it's him who maintains the name->location mapping.

Comment: Ah, I see.. Thanks, I wish I can mark your comment as answered!

Comment: It isn't an answer in any way. It is awfully vague (since I'm not an expert in GPU hardware and driver architecture) and it still doesn't answer what maintenance overhead is likely to be caused by long uniform or attribute names inside the driver.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't make a measurable difference. After linking your program during initialization, query the locations of attributes/uniforms, and keep the result around with the program handle. From then on, neither your app nor the driver will be touching the name strings, just the integer locations.

Even if you re-query locations every time you need to change an attrib binding or uniform value, the difference between a short and "moderate" name length likely won't make much difference compared to the other costs of doing the lookup and binding/value change.